# SQLite difference between latest and second latest row

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have table like this:

```
create table events(
 event_type integer not null,
 value integer not null,
 time timestamp not null,
 unique (event_type ,time)
);

insert into events values
(2,   5,  '2015-05-09 12:42:00'),
(4, -42,  '2015-05-09 13:19:57'),
(2,   2,  '2015-05-09 14:48:39'),
(2,   7,  '2015-05-09 13:54:39'),
(3,  16,  '2015-05-09 13:19:57'),
(3,  20,  '2015-05-09 15:01:09')
```

I would like to see to a query that for each `event_type` that has been registered more than once returns the difference between the latest and the second latest value .

Given the above table, I am expecting following output:

```
event_type  value
  2          -5
  3           4
```

As I know in `SQL Sever/Oracle`, this can be achieved using `row_number() over (partition by)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always simulate `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS
(
     SELECT *,
           (SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 
            FROM "events" e1
            WHERE e1.event_type = e.event_type
              AND e1.time > e.time) AS rn
     FROM "events" e
)
SELECT c.event_type, c."value" - c2."value" AS "value"
FROM cte c
JOIN cte c2
  ON c.event_type = c2.event_type
 AND c.rn = 1 AND c2.rn = 2
ORDER BY event_type, time;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/b8272/23/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═══════════════╦═══════╗
║ event_type    ║ value ║
╠═══════════════╬═══════╣
║            2  ║    -5 ║
║            3  ║     4 ║
╚═══════════════╩═══════╝
```

---

Identifiers like `time/events/value` are reserwed words in some SQL dialects.